# Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/assets/js/lib.js

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the file size of javacript file and I keep getting `Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/assets/js/lib.js`

This is what i'm doing

```
<?php filesize(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'assets/js/lib.js'); ?>
```

I try every solution but its not worked .  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong function `plugin_dir_url()` it returns URL of file, you need file path, use this function instead `plugin_dir_path()`

this is how your code should look like 
`<?php filesize(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'assets/js/lib.js'); ?>`